# Unable to write to Azure datalake from Apache NIFI PUTHDFS processor

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to write to datalake using "PUTHDFS" processor. I've provided core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml files path, additional resources path, directory in puthdfs processor configurations. But, i'm getting the error as in the picture attached. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Jar Files present in the additional resource path:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What JARs did you specify through the Additional Resources property?

Comment: I specified the Directory where all the jar files are located.

Comment: All the Azure JAR files?

Comment: Correct! azure jar files and ojdbc jar file.

Comment: Ok, based on the error message it is saying it can't find the class for NativeAzureFileSystem which should be in one of the JAR files. It might be helpful to show a listing of all the JARs so others who are familiar with Azure can see if it looks correct.

Comment: Yes, please share the list of JARs

Comment: Please have a look at jar files present in the additional resources path provided

Comment: @EagerLearner, please provide full stack trace from the `./log/nifi-app.log` file for the error ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Its resolved after giving full permissions(Read,Write&Execute) to the directory provided in PUTHDFS.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Nifi 1.9.0 which is using Apache Hadoop 3.0.0 .. and I only need 2 jar files to access Azure Datalake gen1 for your "Additional Classpath Resources"

azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.3.1.jar
hadoop-azure-datalake-3.1.1.jar

These jars are available from the Maven central repository.

Then you just need a core-site.xml for your "Hadoop Configuration Resources"

Sample : replace $var with your values

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>adl://$adls-storage-account-name.azuredatalakestore.net</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type</name>
<value>$ClientCredential</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url</name>
<value>https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant-id/oauth2/token</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id</name>
<value>$client id</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.adls.oauth2.credential</name>
<value>$key</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```